# how to open two succesive fancybox windows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am trying to open two fancybox windows. When the first window is closed - the "afterClose" function triggers the next one.

The problem is, that "afterClose" of the SECOND popup is called even BEFORE it is opened. As a result, the closeCallback function of the SECOND popup is being called right away, and the page changes.
(What it should do, is wait until after the user presses the 'OK' button - and THEN change the page).

I tried using a timeout as long as 5 seconds, but it still does not work.

Can anyone please help?...

Thank you!!

---

Just to be clear:

What I want to happen is:
First popup opens. User presses 'OK. First popup closes. Second popup opens. User presses 'OK'. Second popup closes. page changes to home.

What I get now is:

First popup opens. User presses 'OK. First popup closes. Second popup opens for a split of a second, then closes right away and the page changes to home.

```
function openNotificationPopup(message, callback, closeCallback) {

    $('.fancybox-outer').append('<button class="popupBtn">OK</button>');

    $.fancybox.open({
        content: message,
        afterClose: function() {
            if (closeCallback !== undefined) {
                closeCallback();
            } else if (callback !== undefined) {
                callback();
            }
        }
    });


    $(document).on('click', '.popupBtn', function() {
        if (callback !== undefined) {
            callback();
        }
        $.fancybox.close();
    });
}

function openSecondPopup(){
     setTimeout(openNotificationPopup(msg2, gotoGame, goHome),5000);
}

openNotificationPopup(msg1, openSecondPopup, goHome);
```

Comment: Have you tried onClosed instead of afterClose?
http://fancybox.net/api

Comment: @IhorDeyneka : it seems the OP is using fancybox v2.x

Comment: @yogev : you should call `openNotificationPopup()` for the second fancybox after a `click` event of a button, not after a `click` event on the `document`

Comment: @JFK: The button is in an iFrame, which is why i had to use document in the first place. When i try to catch a click on the button directly, it does not work...

Comment: anyways, you are calling the two modal boxes sequentially (one inside `setTimeout`)

Comment: Yes, but I still don't understand why the second one fires the "afterClose" even before it opens;